# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all' after encoding in Python

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I'm getting the following error. I've searched on google enough. But nothing can solve my problem. My problem seems different from others. I'm using `BeautifulSoup`.

I think the following line is creating the problem.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
```

When I'm trying to find all the `div` having a `holder` class:

```
data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"holder"})
```

If shows the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "web_crawler.py", line 32, in 
>       data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"holder"})
>   AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Is `encoding` creating the problem ?

Comment: Why do you encode a `BeautifulSoup` object in the first place? Did you mean to write something like `BeautifulSoup(req.content.encode("utf-8"), 'html.parser')`?

Comment: Before `encoding`, it was showing the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_crawler.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(data); exit()
  File "c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp
437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 13
5: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 5):

Convert `req.content` value to `utf-8` not BS object's value.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content.encode("utf-8"), 'html.parser')

or
```

I'm assume that you're using `requests` module for getting the http responses.

```
req.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: It shows: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_crawler.py", line 29, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content.encode("utf-8"), 'html.parser')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: seems it's already encoded.. before getting it's content, set it's encodig to utf-8 like `req.encoding='utf-8'` then run `soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')`, [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Before encoding, it was showing the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "web_crawler.py", line 33, in <module> print(data); exit() File "c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp 437.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 13 5: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Same as above: `    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 13
5: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 2):

You should encode the html content instead of encoding the BeautifulSoup object like:

```
BeautifulSoup(req.content.encode("utf-8"), 'html.parser')
```